# When using service worker in Angular 8 how can I test using my local rest API endpoint instead of production endpoint?

Tags: angular, localhost, service-worker

In order to test how Service Worker caching is working in my Angular 8 application, as I understand it, I need to test against the production /dist files using "http-server -c-1", which works. However, because I am running against the production /dist files, the program thinks it is in production and therefore uses the production back-end. I would like it to use my local back-end at localhost:3000 while testing Service Worker. Is there a way to do this?

**environment.prod.ts**

```js
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    dataServiceURL: "http:/xxxxxxxxx-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
};
```

**environment.ts**

```js
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    dataServiceURL: "http://localhost:3000/"
};
```

**ngsw-config.json**

```js
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
    "index": "/index.html",
    "assetGroups": [
    {
        "name": "app",
         "installMode": "prefetch",
         "resources": {
             "files": [
                 "/favicon.ico",
                 "/index.html",
                 "/*.css",
                 "/*.js",
                 "/assets/i18n/en.json"
             ]
          }
        }, {
            "name": "assets",
            "installMode": "lazy",
            "updateMode": "prefetch",
            "resources": {
                "files": [
                    "/assets/**",
                    "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani|json)"
                ]
             }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Error shows accessing production rather than localhost:3000 **

> w$ {headers: c$, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url:
>   "http://xxxxxxxxxx-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/posts", ok: false, …}

**UPDATE: Applied suggested fix**

**window.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

function _window(): any {
  // return the global native browser window object
  return window;
}
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WindowService {

  constructor() { }

  get nativeWindow(): any {
    return _window();
  }
}
```

**data.service.ts - new function**

```js
getLocation() {
    const hostLocation = this.WindowRef.nativeWindow.location.host;
    let dataSvcURL = environment.dataServiceURL + 'api/posts';

    console.log('Host location ', hostLocation);

    if (environment.production && hostLocation.includes('localhost')) {
      dataSvcURL = 'http://localhost:3000/' + 'api/posts';
    }

    console.log('Back-end location ', dataSvcURL);
    return dataSvcURL;
  }
```

**Console.log shows override of back-end URL**
Host location  localhost:8080
Back-end location  http://localhost:3000/api/posts

Answer (score 0):

In your angular app, you can make a conditional check if your current host is 'localhost', update the

> environment. dataServiceURL

to point to use local backend service otherwise use the value from the environment. Something like

```
if(environment.production && window.location.hostname === 'localhost') {environment.dataServiceURL = 'http://localhost:3000';}
```

Comment: Thanks Rajesh.  This pointed me in the right direction.  I found, however, it seems that one is supposed to get a reference to the window object, rather than access directly.   So I added a window.service.ts which returns a reference to the window object and then use that in my data service in the manner you suggest.